# ServiceStack CustomUserSession casting exception

Tags: c#, servicestack

**Login.cshtml**

```xml
....
<form action="/auth/credentials">
    <div>
        <span>User Name</span>
        <input name="userName" type="text"/>
    </div><div>
        <span>Password</span>
        <input name="password" type="password"/>
    </div><div>
        <input name="RememberMe" type="checkbox" checked value="true"/>
        <span>Remember me</span>
    </div><div>
        <button class="login">Sign in</button>
    </div>
</form>
....
```

**LoginService.cs**

```
[DefaultView("login")]
public class LoginService : BaseService {
    public object Get(Login req) {
        return new LoginResponse() { UserSession = base.UserSession };
    }
}
```

**BaseService.cs**

```
....
public CustomUserSession UserSession {
    get {
        return SessionAs<CustomUserSession>(); // **** Error here ****        
    }
}
....
```

**Error Message** at `SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();`

> InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
>
> Unable to cast object of type 'ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.AuthUserSession'
>   to type 'MyProject.CustomUserSession'.

I have a simple html form in `login.cshtml` to test out the credentials auth feature. The code is mimicking the credential auth feature part of SocialBootstrapApi demo project.

**Before I updated SS from NuGet:** (packages from about 40 days ago)

If the html form has `RememberMe div`, `SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();` would hit the `InvalidCastException` error. Otherwise it works fine with just `UserName` and `Password` divs in it.

**After I updated SS from NuGet:** (packages updated today 4th Nov v3.9.25.0)

`SessionAs<CustomUserSession>();` always hits the `InvalidCastException` error even when the html form just have `UserName` and `Password` divs in it.

I'm not sure what I have done wrong in the casting process. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your Auth Registration look like?

This is what the AuthConfig of the [SocialBootstrapApi](https://github.com/ServiceStack/SocialBootstrapApi/blob/master/src/SocialBootstrapApi/App_Start/AppHost.cs) project looks like:

```
Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(
    () => new CustomUserSession(), //Use your own typed Custom UserSession type
    new IAuthProvider[] {
        new CredentialsAuthProvider(),              //HTML Form post 
        new TwitterAuthProvider(appSettings),       //Sign-in with Twitter
        new FacebookAuthProvider(appSettings),      //Sign-in with Facebook
        new DigestAuthProvider(appSettings),        //Sign-in with Digest Auth
        new BasicAuthProvider(),                    //Sign-in with Basic Auth
        new GoogleOpenIdOAuthProvider(appSettings), //Sign-in with Goolge OpenId
        new YahooOpenIdOAuthProvider(appSettings),  //Sign-in with Yahoo OpenId
        new OpenIdOAuthProvider(appSettings),       //Sign-in with Custom OpenId
    }));
```

The `new CustomUserSession()` is what tells ServiceStack to use a Custom Session and not the built-in default `AuthUserSession`.

And what CacheClient are you using?

Comment: Thank you so much mythz! I was using the standard UserAuthSession instead of CustomUserSession! You hit the nail on the head!